# ¿Que gestor documental puedo usar para desarrollar mi pagina web?

Tags: aplicación-web, documentacion

estoy desarrollando una pagina web para una pequeña empresa de prueba y dentro de dicha página, se tiene que manejar de forma interna muchos documentos con distintos flujos de trabajo.

He visto distintos gestores documentales como OpenProdoc, OpenKM, nuxeo, etc y no termino de entender muy bien su funcionamiento ya que no se hasta que punto se pueden integrar en mi pagina web.

Si alguien tiene conocimientos sobre estos gestores o conoce algun framework, etc para desarollar  lo indicado.

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En principio, los gestores documentales YA tiene un interfaz web, además optimizado para sus funciones, por lo que, generalmente, no se justifica el desarrollar un interfaz nuevo. El acceso a la mayoría de las funciones debería hacerse por ese interfaz.

No obstante, hay escenarios en que SÍ interesa integrar con otro interfaz.

Por ejemplo, si una aplicación web implica una operación o proceso de la empresa, que además incluye un documento, no tiene sentido que los datos del proceso se introduzcan en una aplicación y los documentos en otra aplicación  (con la pérdida de tiempo y riesgo de incoherencias). En un único interfaz de usuario se rellena todo (documento incluido) , y luego el documento (y sus datos) se almacenan en el gestor documental y los datos "transaccionales" en las BBDD o servicios correspondientes.

Otro escenario en que puede ser necesario es si se intenta "publicar" documentos a usuarios externos o público en general. En ese caso, esas personas no tendrán usuario del gestor documental y, aunque lo tengan, por seguridad no interesa exponer todo el servidor del gestor documental ni utilizar su interfaz completo, que puede ser complejo. En ese caso si puede ser admisible desarrollar n interfaz simplificado que además utilice un usuario genérico de aplicación.

En los casos en que se necesite integrar los servicios del gestor documental, la mayoría ofrecen un interfaz REST.

En el caso de OpenProdoc (http://jhierrot.github.io/openprodoc/index_ES.html) dispones de un interfaz REST para realizar todas las operaciones básicas sobre documentos y carpetas/expedientes (generalmente los documentos formarán parte de una entidad que los aglutine, como un proyecto, departamento o cliente,... y hay métodos para manejar ese expediente).

Se dispone también de un API Java para integrar desde procesos automáticos o desde aplicaciones J2EE.

Respecto a publicación al exterior, OpenProdoc dispone de un interfaz "público" parametrizable (puedes ver un ejemplo en: https://archivo-historico.greenpeace.es )

En breve publicaré un SDK con un manual detallado de desarrollo y ejemplos de diverso tipo.
Si tienes interés, contáctame en privado y puedo adelantarte información.